General lorentz transformation as exponential
I am looking at Lorentz transformations and how the Dirac equation transforms under them. A Lorentz transformation is an element of the matrix group
$$O(1,3) := \left\{\Lambda\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times4} \ \mid \ \Lambda^T\eta\Lambda = \eta\right\},$$
where
$$\eta := \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
-1&&&\\
&1&&\\
&&1&\\
&&&1
\end{array}\right).$$
I am interested in writing these matrices as exponentials $\Lambda = e^{i\Phi}$, where $\Phi\in\mathbb{C}^{4\times4}$ is a self-adjoint matrix wrt. the metric $\eta$, that is $\Phi^\dagger = \Phi$, where adjunction is done like so: $A^\dagger := \eta A^*\eta$. To do this, I am trying to show it is possible to unitarily diagonalize the Lorentz transformations, that is to write
$$\Lambda = UDU^\dagger,$$
for some diagonal $D$ and some $U$ such that $U^\dagger U = U U^\dagger = 1$. Is this possible? I know that the spectral theorem for self-adjoint matrices fails when the inner product/metric is not positive definite, but merely non-degenerate. However, Lorentz transformations are orthogonal matrices wrt. the metric $\eta$, not self-adjoint.
Furthermore, I know Lie theory describes how you can write elements in the connected component of $O(1,3)$ that contains the identity as exponentials of Lie algebra elements, but that does not capture the full group that includes reflections. I can perhaps go with the Lie group approach and start with some specific Lorentz transformation for each connected component of $O(1,3)$ as inital condition in the ODEs generated by the Lie algebra elements and try to reach every Lorentz transformation that way, but that sounds more complicated...

Not all Lorentzian transformations are complex-diagonalizable.

Do you know an example?

Start by working out the case of $SO(2,1)$ and it's element that has a light-like eigenvector with eigenvalue  1. Then compute it's Jordan normal form.

In a compact semisimple Lie group, all elements are semisimple (diagonalisable over $\mathbb{C}$)  but this is rarely (if ever?) true for a noncompact group. They contain unipotent elements in general which are certainly not diagonalisable

The Lorentz group $\mathit {SO}(1,3)$ is generated by the $\mathit{SO}(3)$ subgroup of and a boost, eg in 1,2-plane
$$\exp{\left(u\ \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1&0&0 \\
 1 & 0&0&0 \\
 0 & 0&0&0 \\
 0 & 0&0&0 \\
\end{pmatrix}\right)} =   \begin{pmatrix}
 \cosh u & \sinh u&0&0 \\
 \sinh u & \cosh u&0&0 \\
 0 & 0&1&0 \\
 0 & 0&0&1 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$
By the invariance of the Lorentz metric G-product for any two vectors $x,y$, $$G(x,y)= x^T \cdot g\ \cdot y = G(\Lambda x,\Lambda y)= (\Lambda x)^T\cdot   g \cdot \Lambda  \cdot y= x^T\cdot  \left(\Lambda^T g \cdot \Lambda \right) \cdot y$$
$$g\cdot \Lambda^T g \Lambda =1,\quad  g\cdot \Lambda^T \cdot g = \Lambda^{-1}  .$$
This all boils down to $\det \Lambda =1$. The special euclidean orthogonality of the space vectors at universal constant time is lost by boosts.
The full Lorentz group has four distinct components continuously path-connected with the four diagonal matrices $$(1,1,1,1), \quad (-1,-1,1,1),\quad (-1,1,1,1), \quad (1,-1,1,1)$$.
The identity component as the central subgroup  can be parametrizised using the 6 elements of the Lie-algebra $L_i$ generating rotations around a vector axis $\vec n$ and a boost in the plane of the time axis and a velocity vector $\vec u$
$$\Lambda\left(\vec n, \vec u\right) = \exp \left( \vec n \cdot.\vec L  +  \vec u \cdot \vec K\right)$$
with the antsymmetric generators of rotation (instead an 'i' factor)  $$(L_i)_{kl}= \epsilon_{ikl}$$
but symmetric boost generators $K_i$, producing hyperbolic functions by exponentiation.
$$K_{i,j}=0, \quad \text{except} \quad (K_i)_{1,l} = (K_i)_{l,1}   $$
Of course, you may insert a factor $-i^2$ in the exponent and work with imaginary angles and velocities and a mix of hermitean and antihermitean generator matrices, but for what intention?

In this question I am talking about the general Lorentz group that includes all kinds of reflections, not the special Lorentz group.

$\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda = \eta$ implies $\det\Lambda = \pm1$ , not $\det\Lambda = 1$.

No difference, the three dicrete mirror matrice $t\to -t,  x\to -x , (t,x)\to -(t,x)$ produce signs, that disappear in the quadratic condition for $\Lambda$

The question is: given $\Lambda\in O(1,3)$ (not $SO(1,3)$), is there a complex matrix $\Phi$ so that $\Lambda = e^{i\Phi}$ and $\Phi^* = \eta\Phi\eta$?

@Rasmus Certainly there is not as $\exp$ only ever maps onto the connected component of the identity. In this case, $\exp$ is surjective onto that component (what physicists would call the proper orthochronous subgroup) but that is an oddity among non-compact groups and is a little difficult to prove (see here)

Yes. I see. Thanks for the answers, but I figured out I can describe how the Dirac equation transforms without matrix exponentials.
